# How to get azure cache for Redis connection string stored in app service as Appsetting variable

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I have created a azure redis for cache and stored the connection string as application setting variable in app service using terraform. Now I want my code to access the connection string. In the existing application we explictly mentioned the connection string in web.config. So now I needed to get the azure application variable via code.

Comment: What is the framework and version of your Application?

Comment: .Net framework 4.7.2 @Harshitha

Comment: have you tried just using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_env_var_name")`?!

Comment: I just rephrased the title. The connection string is stored in the app service as app setting variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache#connect-to-the-cache-with-redisconnection) to set and retrieve Redis Cache Connection String.

***My `Web.config` file App Setting:***

```cs
 <appSettings>
    <add key="RedisCacheConn" value="HarshuRedisCache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=**********=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"/>
 </appSettings>
```

***In Controller :***

```cs
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string RCConn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedisCacheConn"].ToString();
            string rediscon = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RedisCacheConn");
            ViewBag.RCConn = RCConn.ToString();
            if (rediscon != null)
            {
                ViewBag.rediscon = rediscon.ToString();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

***Index.cshtml :***

```cs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h5> <b>With ConfigurationManager </b> - @ViewBag.RCConn</h5>
    <h5> <b>With Environment Variable</b> - @ViewBag.rediscon</h5>
</div>
```

Thanks @Silent for the Comment.

As mentioned by Silent we can also use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RedisCacheConn");` to retrieve the App setting variable.

For this we need to set the App setting in the Configuration Section of the `App Service`.

[image]

- This is for the deployed Azure Web App.
- To get the value with `Environment` variable locally, we need to set the value locally.

***Local Output:***
[image]

***Azure App Service Output:***

[image]